# Under what conditions the point $z$ is unique in its range of existence?

Tags: real-analysis

**Theorem**: Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$. If the range of $f$ contains $[a,b]$, then the equation $f(x)=x$ has at least one solution $z$ in $[a,b]$, i.e., $f(z)=z$.

My **question** is:
Under what conditions the point $z$ is unique in its range of existence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sufficient condition:
$$
|f(x)-f(y|<|x-y|\quad\forall x,y\in[a,b].
$$

Comment: First, I assume you mistyped $[0,1]$ instead of $[a,b]$. We have: $\forall (x,y) \in [a,b]^2, \quad |f(x)-f(y)| < |x-y| \leq b-a$. Let $x_a \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_a) = a$. We know this point exists because $[a,b]$ is in the range of $f$. Then we have: $\forall y \in [a,b], \quad |f(x_a) - f(y)| = |f(y)-a| < b-a$. This proves that no $y$ exists such that $f(y) = b$. A contradiction with the hypohesis.